# How to get the returned value in a Windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, gulp

In Windows batch file I want the return value i.e. the apkVerison number. When I run gulp getVersion on the command line or inside a batch file it works fine. I want save the version number to a variable inside the batch file.

```
gulpfile.js:
  gulp.task('getVersion', function () {
      var data = require('./package.json')
      console.log('Version = ' + data.apkDependencies.apkVersion)
      return data.apkDependencies.apkVersion;
    });

abc.bat:
    set x=gulp getVersion 
    echo %x%
```

The batch file does not work. echo just echos "gulp getVersion"

Sorry I should have mentioned when I run gulp this is its output

```
gulp getVersion
[22:16:44] Using gulpfile ~\CareWheelsCorp\CareWheels\gulpfile.js
[22:16:44] Starting 'getVersion'...
Version = 9.1.13
[22:16:44] Finished 'getVersion' after 1.91 ms
```

As you can see Version is hidden inside, I need that 9.1.13 number

Answer (score 1):

It works perfectly happily - just as you have asked it to do, to `echo` the contents of `x`.

If you want to *execute* the contents of `x`, you need

```
%x%
```

and if you want to get the return value, you need

```
for /f "delims=" %%r in ('%x%') do set "return=%%r"
echo %return%
```

(assuming that the executable responds with a result from `stdout`)

---

Given the clarification,

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims== " %%r in ('%x%') do if "%%r"=="Version" set "return=%%s"
echo %return%
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned when I run gulp this is its output

gulp getVersion
[22:16:44] Using gulpfile ~\CareWheelsCorp\CareWheels\gulpfile.js
[22:16:44] Starting 'getVersion'...
Version = 9.1.13
[22:16:44] Finished 'getVersion' after 1.91 ms

As you can see Version is hidden inside, I need thatr 9.1.13 number.

Comment: Please edit this data into your question as it's not possible to see where line breaks may be, nor is it all that easy to scry what information you wish to use from this return.

Comment: I have edited my original question please check it out. So @Magoo thanks for your answer but it does not work. Sorry I had given incomplete info.

Comment: Well anticipated :)

Comment: Wow! @Magoo you are super fast and it worked. Thanks a lot. I am done!!